# Regex - обязательное наличие символов в некоторой подстроке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая задача: в базе есть строки, оканчиваются схожим образом, примерно так: `Т20NE99`, `P678SE`, `L99В0` и т.п. То есть эти строки могут быть разной длины, но находятся всегда в конце и отделяются от остальной части пробелом. В некоторых из подобных подстрок вместо английских символов записаны русские, мне нужно отыскать, где именно и отредактировать их. Написал такую регулярку: `[ТМРВЕКХСАA-Z0-9]+$`, но потом вспомнил, что в квадратных скобках символы ищутся через ИЛИ, то есть русские символы могут как существовать, так и нет, и этот вариант, разумеется, не подходит. Не могу припомнить, как можно указать, что какие-то символы должны присутствовать в подстроке обязательно? В данном случае - русские символы `ТМРВЕКХСA`, имеющие английские аналоги.

Answer (score 0):

Если русских букв вообще не должно быть, то я бы искал просто

```
[ТМРВЕКХСA]
```

Если русские буквы в принципе бывают, но надо проверить их наличие в последних 7 символах:

```
[ТМРВЕКХСA].{0,6}$
```

Если надо ещё и строки, оканчивающиеся определёнными символами при этом найти, то (с квадратичной асимптотикой поиска):

```
(?=.*[ТМРВЕКХСA])[ТМРВЕКХСАA-Z0-9]{1,7}$
```

Comment: Последнее выражение близко к тому, что мне нужно, вот только в вопросе я забыл указать (сейчас дополнил): длина может быть разной, отделяется эта подстрока пробелом. Я указал так: " [ТМРВЕКХСА].{2,7}?$", с пробелом в начале, чтобы регулярка смотрела только на подстроку, но она идет дальше и берет вторую подстроку с конца, даже если я указываю ленивый квантификатор, хотя, например, если в последней подстроке 3 символа, то она удовлетворяет заданному шаблону от 2 до 7 символов.

Comment: @Jeep, а если подумать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
[\u0422\u041C\u0420\u0412\u0415\u041A\u0425\u0421\u0410](?=\S*$)
[ТМРВЕКХСА](?=\S*$)
```

См. пример использования выражения.

- `[ТМРВЕКХСА]` - буква `Т`, `М`, `Р`, `В`, `Е`, `К`, `Х`, `С` или А`
- `(?=\S*$)` - от текущей позиции и до конца строки должно быть 0 и более непробельных символов.